# How to upgrade gnu make in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, homebrew

Currently I am at:

```
mhoggan-C02S81PRG8WM:c_velodyne mhoggan$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free
software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty;
not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
mhoggan-C02S81PRG8WM:c_velodyne mhoggan$ make --version GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free
software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty;
not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Is there a way with Homebrew to upgrade to 4.1 or 4.2?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can run:

```
brew install homebrew/core/make
```

on earlier systems this was:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/make
```

This will install make 4.2.1.

Another option, if you want to retain the system installed make version, is to install remake instead.

```
brew install remake
```

Comment: For the first command, I get "Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: They are now at homebrew-core, I have updated the answer. (The answer was from 2016).

Answer (score 3):

By default homebrew installs GNU make binary with "g" prefix, as: `/usr/local/bin/gmake`

If you want to install it as `make` run:

`brew install --with-default-names make`

Then it will "cover" system's default `make` assuming `/usr/local/bin` preceeds `/usr/bin` (where the system's `make` resides) in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-default-names

Answer (score 2):

As [Michał Szajbe points out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336443/353815), this will install with a `g` prefix.

The more up to date solution (to make `gmake` the default `make`) is to modify your PATH:

Edit your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` etc

```
...
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Running `make --version` should now reflect the `brew` installed version.